# calculating binary tree internal nodes

Tags: binary-search-tree

I could find a question related to full binary tree.

A full binary tree is a rooted tree in which every internal node has exactly two children. How many internal
nodes are there in a full binary tree with 500 leaves?

I feels the answer as 250. Please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any two leaves and combine them to create an internal node. Now, you can increase by one the number of internal nodes and delete the two used leaves, which transforms than internal node in a new leaf.

Thus, if we call `f(n)` the number of internal nodes with n leaves, the previous argument leads us to `f(n) = 1 + f(n - 1)`, where `f(2) = 1`. Therefore, `f(n) = n - 1`.

Thus, for 500 the result is 499.

Answer (score -1):

If full binary tree (T) has 500 leaves (L), then the number of internal nodes is I = L – 1 i.e  I = 500 - 1.

```
Result is 499.
```